# Same code, different systems and different data type intepretation

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database which the schema was created and I imported data from excel (they exported it from their SQL Server database into excel format)

I am running SQL Server 2008R2 + updates
They are running SQL Express 2008 R2

The problem is, on my system I am reading the values using .NET. A specific column of type decimal should actually be of double (unable to change it in production unfortunately)

For a specific data set, the value of this column is "0"

on my side, I read the data using GetDouble and that is fine - it gives me "0.0" (even though the actual value stored in the table is "0")

on their side, they get an error saying it cannot cast it to the right type. The value they get when they read is "0"

how can this be? I mean, same code completely, same database types, same data but reads it differently?

I am not sure how to go about fixing this or where to look on why the reading is different on both databases?

I would appreciate any help.

I am using stored procedures if it helps (although it shouldn't) to read the data and using the SqlDataReader class to read the incoming data.

here is the code I use to read the data from the SqlDataReader:

```
DedicatedResourceAssetCount = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("dedicated resource asset count")) ? null : new Nullable<double>(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("dedicated resource asset count")))
```

And plenty more properties similar to the above. 
On my machine, the field stored in the DB is 0 and when the reader reads it, it is 0.0
On their machine, the field stored in the DB is 0 and when the reader reads it, it is 0 but of course, throws an InvalidCastException.

Comment: When you say you are running SQL Server 2008 and they're running Express are we talking management studio versions here or two actual database servers? Because if it is different servers, there might be differences in the databases and therefore different datatypes for the field?

Comment: actual database servers.... this is what I need to know is what is the difference and how to find the differences. AFAIK, the culture is English UK, as is mine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to connect via management studio and similar and check whether the table definitions are the same? Sounds like different datatypes to me. Perhaps try and run Red Gates SQL Compare to identify possible schema changes, or similar tools.

Comment: Table definitions are TOTALLY the same.

Comment: How does your query look in regards of selecting this field?

And this is the only double/decimal column where this is happening? If you only have one field for double - try adding a second. Because if the same happens there - then you're back to the culture possibility and that some transformation is actually happening.

Comment: This is one of many fields that has the same data type. I noticed the problem on this field first because it is the first field, of many, I am reading. In terms of the select query, pretty simple: SELECT [field] FROM [table] WHERE [field] = @param. Honestly, this is the query and nothing complicated or inner joins or anything - a simple select query with a where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around, which I really do not like, seems to be the following:

```
object value = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("column"));
double returnResult = Convert.ToDouble(value.ToString());
```

it seems to work but still odd on why it works fine in the original code on my systems.

Answer (score 3):

A far shot is that floating point numbers are interpreted differently on the two systems. In many cultures the dot is used as a decimal separator but in other cultures the comma is used:

- 0.0
- 0,0

Is the second number a comma separated list of two integer zeroes or the floating point number 0.0? "My" and "their" system may use different cultures explaining the unexpected results you have.

However, the culture should only affect the interpretation of numbers if there is some form of conversion from text to number going on in your system. From your explanation it seems that you are querying a database and if the column type is a floating point the decimal separator should not matter.

Still, you could have a look at your system and the data in the system and look for problems with regard to the culture.

Going a bit more into the details of your question it seems that the error "their" system experiences is that `reader.GetDouble` throws an `InvalidCastException`. This means that the data stored in "their" database has another schema than "my" database and the column does not contain a double precision floating point number as expected. You have clearly stated that this is not the case but to find the source of the error you have to continue looking for unexpected differences between "my" and "their" system explaining the exception you get.

Comment: good guess but seems it is English UK for the culture - just like on my systems. So sadly, this was not a solution :(

Comment: I don't believe the language changes how the data is stored either, a double is a double - it's only the display that's different unless stored in a varchar or similar.

Comment: indeed. I agree. Hmm. This is totally weird. Cultures seems to be same on both machines (mine and theirs).

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: That is why I wrote that there have to be some conversion from text to number somewhere for this to be a problem. Excel is mentioned in the question and when you export to CSV you get floating point numbers with either dot or comma depending on the culture but apparently this is not an issue. You are right that the representation of a floating point number in a database does not depend on culture.

Comment: I can assure you, the data itself is the same. :) But for whatever reason, it works fine on mine and not theirs. Both the data values is "0" in the decimal column. not 0.0 but 0. When reading on my system, it brings it back as 0.0 but on theirs its 0 thus the error being occured

Comment: ok, it seems that their systems (the machine) is set to Eng US. I still don't think this should make a difference?